# Android, текст в TextView частично не видим

Tags: java, android, android-layout

Я использую Android Studio Flamingo. Мне нужно создать таблицу из двух столбцов так, чтобы в них были разные шрифты. Для этого у меня есть два TextView, которые я потом добавляю в TableRow, а его в свою очередь в TableLayout. В первом TextView шрифт 30, во втором 20:

```
public void init_words_list() throws IOException {
    TableLayout stk = findViewById(R.id.table_main);
    TypedValue typedValue = new TypedValue();
    getTheme().resolveAttribute(com.google.android.material.R.attr.colorOnSecondary, typedValue, true);
    int text_color = ContextCompat.getColor(this, typedValue.resourceId);
    String[] dict = { "A", "qwerty, qwerty, qwerty" };
    double[] widths = { 0.6, 0.4 };
    int[] heights = { 30, 20 };
    TableRow tbrow = new TableRow(this);
    for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
        TextView tv = new TextView(this);
        tv.setText(dict[i]);
        tv.setWidth((int) Math.round(widths[i] * (stk.getWidth())));
        tv.setTextSize(heights[i]);
        tv.setTextColor(text_color);
        tv.setGravity(Gravity.START);
        tbrow.addView(tv);
    }
    stk.addView(tbrow);
}
```

В итоге получается такой результат:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как я понимаю, высота TextView вычисляется до его добавления в TableRow. А после добавления тексты во обоих TextView выравниваются по нижней границе строки. И из-за того, что шрифт в первом столбце больше, во втором сверху образовывается пустое место, а снизу текст уезжает за пределы ячейки.

Если, например, сделать в первом столбце шрифт 15, получится вот так:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Но такой шрифт мне не подойдёт. Я вижу два решения этой проблемы. Первый - отключить каким-то образом выравнивание текст в разных TextView одного TableRow. Второй - адаптировать высоту TextView после добавления в TableRow. Но я не знаю как реализовать ни один, ни второй.

Comment: Попробуйте вызвать `requestLayout()` у таблицы после того как все в нее добавите. https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TableLayout#requestLayout()

Comment: @EugeneKrivenja вызвал после stk.addView(tbrow); Ничего не поменялось.

Comment: А `init_words_list()` у вас когда вызывается?

Comment: @EugeneKrivenja в самом конце MainActivity.onCreate()

Comment: Попробуйте тогда `requestLayout()` вызвать с некоторой задержкой, например (Kotlin) `stk.postDelayed( { stk.requestLayout() }, 250)`. Костыль конечно, но хотя бы причина будет ясна.

Comment: @EugeneKrivenja Написал на Джаве так: `stk.postDelayed( new Runnable() { @Override public void run() { stk.requestLayout(); } }, 250);` после добавления строки. Ничего не поменялось.